# Characterisation of DVR via invertible ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am reading [these notes](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math205bS10/Math205b_S10_9.pdf).
In terms of the proof of proposition 9.17, I understand the writer used proposition 9.5 to show this. However, to use proposition 9.5, we should check before if our local domain $A$ is of dimension one and this fact was not verified in the notes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in the document you mention there is no proposition 9.7 — numbering is continuous, and there's only an Exercise 9.7.

Comment: I am so sorry. I just amended it.

Comment: Which direction are you asking about?

Comment: Don't be sorry: typos happen to all of us :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathfrak m$ is principal ($A$ local noetherian with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$), then $\dim A\le 1$ by Krull's Hauptidealsatz (*Principal Ideal Theorem*).